# How do I implement a continuous time window in CEP?

Tags: wso2, esper, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Say I have a stream of events and I want to be able to count how many of them there are in a time window. I would like to receive notification whenever an event enters the time window and changes the count and the same when an event exits the time window.

The below illustration show what I mean. I'm using a time window of length 4 and I want 3 notifications, one when the first event enters the window, the second when the second event enters and the third when the first event exits the time window.

[image]

How do I make a query that does that? What if I also want to group by an event's property?

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't give me a notification when an event leaves the window: `@config(async = 'true') define stream myStream (symbol string, timeStamp long) @info(name = 'query1') from myStream#window.externalTime(timeStamp,10 sec)  select symbol, timeStamp, count(timeStamp) as eventCount group by symbol insert into outputStream`. This is for SIddhi CEP, but I imagine Esper would be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From any type of a window in WSO2 CEP, you can expect two types of events.

1. Current events - these are triggered when a new event enters the window. i.e. the new event itself is used as a trigger
2. Expired events - these are triggered when an existing event in the window exits it. i.e. in case of a time window of 1 minute, each event is kept for 1 minute and emitted at the end of 1 minute

You can also use a combination of these two in the same query to trigger it from both types of events.

An example query that uses both types of triggers in CEP 3.1.0 will be (check the [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Windows)):

```
from StockExchangeStream[symbol == 'WSO2']#window.time( 1 minute ) 
select max(price) as maxPrice, avg(price) as avgPrice, min(price) as minPrice
insert into WSO2StockQuote for all-events
```

if you want this to be triggered only using expired events, use 'expired-events' in place of 'all-events'. Same applies for current-events. If you don't specify anything, it defaults to current-events, that's why your current query doesn't get triggered for expired events.

Note that for CEP 4.0.0 the syntax is a bit different, for correct syntax check the [test source codes here](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/window/TimeWindowTestCase.java) (since the docs are still work-in-progress).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm using Siddhi 3.0.0-M1. The query is `@config(async = 'true') define stream myStream (symbol string, timeStamp long) @info(name = 'query1') from myStream#window.externalTime(timeStamp,10 sec)  select symbol, timeStamp, count(timeStamp) as eventCount group by symbol insert all events into outputStream` (note the external time). But I still only get events when an event enters the time window.

Comment: that's because you are using an external time window which uses an external time stamp. so the window compares times of existing events against the times of new incoming events to expire them and emit. if it's not mandatory to use an external time, just use the plain time window, #window.time(10 sec)

Comment: also, try to use the alpha/beta or the latest snapshot of siddhi since it contains fixes to many bugs in M1.

Comment: That worked. But the remove-events are getting called with the wrong timestamp. Looking at the test case [here](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/release-3.0.0-Alpha/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/window/ExternalTimeWindowTestCase.java) the remove events are getting invoked with timestamp instead of timestamp + timeWindowLength (e.g. I would expect the first event to expire at 1366335804341 (its timestamp) + 5000 (time window length)). Any ideas?

Comment: That's actually the expected behaviour. The window just keeps events and emits them once expired, doesn't modify anything. There's an extension to get the system timestamp and you can probably use that to insert it to the events inside the 'select' clause.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wrote. Since I'm using an externally timed window I don't want to interact with system time at all. In your second comment you wrote "the window compares times of existing events against the times of new incoming events to expire them and emit", which is what I would expect. So if the window is 5 secs long and an event comes in at 1 sec I would expect to see an expiration event at t=6 before the first incoming event with timestamp t>=6 comes in. Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: pls ignore the suggestion in previous comment as i misunderstood the requirement. It seems for your requirement the time window (window.time()) is sufficient as you keep every event in window for 10 seconds. For external time windows, expired events are emitted only when a new event arrives if newEventTimestamp > oldEventTimestamp + windowTimeLength. The reason is, in external time windows, there's no way for siddhi to know the current 'external time' unless a new event arrives with the latest external timestamp, so it waits for a new event to compare timestamps and expire them.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I should have been looking at `event.getTimestamp()` instead of `event.getData(0)` in order to get the timestamp of the event. Thanks!